# TextField button that has ideal size, but does not increase beyond edges of the screen?

Tags: swiftui, textfield

In swiftUI, I want to have `TextField` that when text is input, has the width relative to width of current content. I can achieve this by adding `.fixedSize()` modifier. Problem is if I input too much text, width at some point will be bigger than screen size.

What I want to achieve is for `TextField` to have size of content, until some maxWidth is reached, in this case scree width?

Edit: Thanks guys for swift :-) answers (I will give you upvotes), I have to mention that I have one additional request that makes a little difficult:

[image]

As you see I have `TetxField` and then this text after it. I have written code, based on your answers, but could not get it just right:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var text: String
    @State private var textField = ""
    @State private var width: CGFloat = 10
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                
                TextField(text.isEmpty ? "Enter Text" : "", text: $text)
                    .truncationMode(.tail)
                    .frame(maxWidth: proxy.size.width)
                    .fixedSize()
            }
            
            Text(".package.com")
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(height: 24)
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `.frame(maxWidth)` to limit the max width of the text field, just make sure to add it before `.fixedSize()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without a geometry reader: https://www.magnuskahr.dk/posts/2023/05/swiftui-trailing-label-textfield/

Comment: Nice solution. But links get broken (you can fins so many old answers like that on SO) so I would also ask you to copy code here, in addition to leaving a link.

Answer (score 1):

As **Ranoiaetep** already mentioned you can use  `.frame(maxWidth)` I can only add to use `GeometryReader` to set content (screen) width as maxWidth

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            TextField("Placeholder", text: $text)
            
                .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width*0.95, alignment: .leading)
                .fixedSize()
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a TextField that dynamically adjusts its width based on its content but doesn't exceed a certain maximum width (e.g., the screen width), you can use a combination of **GeometryReader** and **frame**. Here's a SwiftUI solution:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                TextField("Enter Text", text: $text)
                    .truncationMode(.tail)
                    .frame(width: min(proxy.size.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16)) // Set the max width here
            }
            
            Text(".package.com")
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(height: 24)
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
    }
}
```